# Why is it necessary that test functions have finite support?

Tags: distribution-theory

For example, if $\phi(x)$ is a test function, which means smooth and with finite support the following is true:
$$\lim\limits_{n->\infty} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta_n(x)\phi(x)\mathrm{d}x = \phi(0)$$
I don't see why it is necessary to restrict $\phi(x)$ to have finite support, wouldn't this be true for every smooth function?

Comment: What is $\delta_n(x)$?

Comment: It's some element of a delta sequence that converges uniformly to the dirac function.

Comment: Are these functions assumed to have compact support?  Otherwise those integrals need not even exist if $\phi$ does not have compact support...

Comment: Is "it might not converge" not a good enough answer?

Comment: No, just smooth. Which ones wouldn't exist?

Comment: if you replace "smooth with compact support" by "smooth and all derivatives are fast decreasing" (the [Schwarz functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space)) then you get the tempered distributions instead of the distributions. those tempered distributions are simpler in the sense that they have a Fourier transform, but for proving it, you'll use the smooth compactly supported functions. also, it is not always easy to see if a function is Schwartz, while seeing that a function is a test function really is not complicated.

Comment: finally, many distributions are well-defined not only when integrated other test functions, but on a much larger class of function,  but for defining those distributions you needed at first the test/Schwartz functions.

Comment: @Euler....IS_ALIVE I have a proof for the relation but It's about two pages long. It only uses the fact, that $\max\limits_{x \in (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)} |\phi(x)-\phi(0)|$ with $\varepsilon > 0$ equals $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} |\phi(x)-\phi(0)| = 0$. This is true for every smooth function.

Comment: @user1952009 Yes, but still it kind of seemed odd to me to "just define the functions like that" "to be sure", even though it's not necessary. That is why I think there might a very clear reason to choose them like that.

Comment: $\delta$ is a very simple example of distribution, and in practice we often write $\int_a^b \delta(x) f(x) dx$ even when $f$ is not a test  or Schwartz function

Comment: and for defining the distributions in general (not only $\delta$ !!!) you need some sort of test functions. the Schwartz functions where used for a long time, and then they discovered that it was easier and more rigorous with the smooth functions with compact support (for which there is really no problem of convergence)

Comment: @user1952009 Ok, sounds reasonable. Could you write an example for such a proof as an answer (or a link or something)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The requirement of $\phi$ having compact support allows us to interpret every locally integrable function $f$ as a distribution, because the integral $\int f\phi$ is guaranteed to converge (and have the right kind of continuity properties) as long as $f$ is locally integrable.

Allowing  $\phi$ to have unbounded support comes with a tradeoff: some assumption must be made about the behavior of $f$ at infinity. The standard example is the definition of tempered distributions, which allows unbounded support of test functions $\phi$, provided that $\phi$   decays faster than any power of $x$. Then $\int f\phi$ converges provided that $f$ is bounded by some polynomial. But for example, $f(x) = e^x$ is not a tempered distribution.

Comment: Minor correction: the definition of *Schwarz functions* allows your "test functions" to have unbounded support while requiring adequate decay. The tempered distributions are the distributions that can be defined on the Schwarz space. Tempered distributions *themselves* do not have to decay at infinity (because there is already decay built into the test functions on which they act). Instead they merely need to not *grow too fast* at infinity, as you have said.

Comment: That's what I meant, but perhaps the wording was unclear. Clarified.

Comment: I think it was confusing because you're sort of putting the cart before the horse by introducing tempered distributions before you introduce Schwarz functions. It is still a little bit awkward for the same reason.